# Modified bus scheduling problem in ortools

Tags: python, schedule, or-tools

I want to modify the [bus scheduling problem from ortools](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/bus_driver_scheduling_sat.py) so as each driver's shift to be consecutive in terms of slots and drivers can share a shift at the same time if needed.

For example, assuming that we have the following half-hour shifts (format similar to the original bus_scheduling_problem from ortools):

```
shifts = [
[0, '07:00', '07:30', 420, 450, 30],
[1, '07:30', '08:00', 450, 480, 30],
[2, '08:00', '08:30', 480, 510, 30],
[3, '08:30', '09:00', 510, 540, 30],
[4, '09:00', '09:30', 540, 570, 30],
[5, '09:30', '10:00', 570, 600, 30],
[6, '10:00', '10:30', 600, 630, 30],
[7, '10:30', '11:00', 630, 660, 30],
[8, '11:00', '11:30', 660, 690, 30],
[9, '11:30', '12:00', 690, 720, 30],
[10, '12:00', '12:30', 720, 750, 30],
[11, '12:30', '13:00', 750, 780, 30],
[12, '13:00', '13:30', 780, 810, 30],
[13, '13:30', '14:00', 810, 840, 30],
[14, '14:00', '14:30', 840, 870, 30],
[15, '14:30', '15:00', 870, 900, 30],
[16, '15:00', '15:30', 900, 930, 30],
[17, '15:30', '16:00', 930, 960, 30],
[18, '16:00', '16:30', 960, 990, 30],
[19, '16:30', '17:00', 990, 1020, 30],
[20, '17:00', '17:30', 1020, 1050, 30],
[21, '17:30', '18:00', 1050, 1080, 30],
[22, '18:00', '18:30', 1080, 1110, 30],
[23, '18:30', '19:00', 1110, 1140, 30],
[24, '19:00', '19:30', 1140, 1170, 30],
[25, '19:30', '20:00', 1170, 1200, 30],
[26, '20:00', '20:30', 1200, 1230, 30],
[27, '20:30', '21:00', 1230, 1260, 30],
[28, '21:00', '21:30', 1260, 1290, 30],
[29, '21:30', '22:00', 1290, 1320, 30],
[30, '22:00', '22:30', 1320, 1350, 30],
[31, '22:30', '23:00', 1350, 1380, 30],
[32, '23:00', '23:30', 1380, 1410, 30],
[33, '23:30', '24:00', 1410, 1440, 30]
]
```

I successfully execute the [this version of the bus_scheduling code](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/bus_driver_scheduling_flow_sat.py) and I find that I need 2 drivers to satisfy the needs for the above mentioned schedule. The range of working hours is from `07:00 am to 24:00 (midnight)`.

As a result, if we have 2 bus drivers for this schedule, I would prefer an allocation that covers the daily duty based on 12-h driver shift as following:

```
Driver 1: 07:00 - 19:00 with a break at 13:00
Driver 2: 12:00 - 24:00 with a break at 14:00 (basically no overlap with Driver 1's break)
```

What I mean by consecutive hours is that solutions that satisfy a **12-h driver** shift solution in the form of `07:00-11:00 + 14:00-15:00 + 17:00-24:00` should **not** be acceptable. Solutions with more drivers should also make sure that breaks are not overlapping so as **not** all drivers are on break. Moreover, slots for breaks can be blocked due to high work load.

I got an *answer* at the *or-tools discussion* saying that I need to maintain at each node the total time since the start of the shift, but I'm having difficulty in coding that assuming it solves my question.

Comment: I summarises constraints and added a question here - https://pastebin.com/UhVg7q0p . Could you please take a look?

Comment: Additionally, can shifts differ? In your example, all of them are 30 mins, but can it be that some of them are `30` and others `40` or something else?

Comment: It seems it's in the right direction. The possible working hour range though should be 07:00 - 00:00 or 07:30: 00:00. Optimally start - finish should be given as inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, [bus scheduling problem from ortools](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/bus_driver_scheduling_sat.py) is an overkill for your task since you mentioned that shift durations are always `30` minutes, and setup/cleanup time is not needed. Moreover, drivers must work exactly `11` hours and have a contiguous break. Instead, we could write a script similar to [nurse scheduling problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling) that is probably easier to understand (for me, it was the first time writing something with **or-tools** and it was clear).

## Preparation

First, the total number of shifts can be calculated as below:

```
num_shifts = len(shifts)
```

Number of drivers needed:

```
num_drivers = ceil(float(num_shifts) / working_time)
```

In your case, driver must drive exactly `11` hours, and so it's `22` shifts (each shift is fixed at `30` minutes):

```
working_time = 22
```

Break is `1` hour so:

```
break_time = 2
```

As you mentioned in the comment, each driver must take a break after `4` hours of driving, but not later than after `8` hours:

```
break_interval = [8, 16]
```

The latest shift when a driver can start working:

```
latest_start_shift = num_shifts - working_time - break_time
```

Really, if he/she starts working later, then the driver won't work off the full working time.

## Build Model

Let's define an array of shifts for drivers:

```
driver_shifts = {}
for driver_id in range(num_drivers):
    for shift_id in range(num_shifts):
        driver_shifts[(driver_id, shift_id)] = model.NewBoolVar('driver%ishift%i' % (driver_id, shift_id))
```

`driver_shifts[(d, s)]` equals `1` if shift `s` is assigned to driver `d`, and `0` otherwise.

Additionally, create an array of start shifts for drivers:

```
start_time = {}
for driver_id in range(num_drivers):
    for shift_id in range(latest_start_shift + 1):
        start_time[(driver_id, shift_id)] = model.NewBoolVar('driver%istart%i' % (driver_id, shift_id))
```

`start_time[(d, s)]` equals `1` if driver `d` starts a working day at shift `s`, and `0` otherwise.

### Driver drives exactly 11 hours per day

Each driver must drive exactly the required driving time within the day:

```
for driver_id in range(num_drivers):
    model.Add(sum(driver_shifts[(driver_id, shift_id)] for shift_id in range(num_shifts)) == working_time)
```

However, it's not enough since the driver must do it contiguously with one break in between. We will see how to do this later.

### All shifts are covered by drivers

Each shift must be covered by at least one driving driver:

```
for shift_id in range(num_shifts):
    model.Add(sum(driver_shifts[(driver_id, shift_id)] for driver_id in range(num_drivers)) >= 1)
```

### Driver drives contiguously

Here where `start_time` comes into play. The basic idea is that for each possible start time of driver, we enforce that the driver works off the time (physically, a driver can start working only once day!).

So, driver can start working only once per day:

```
for driver_id in range(num_drivers):
    model.Add(sum(start_time[(driver_id, start_shift_id)] for start_shift_id in range(latest_start_shift + 1)) == 1)
```

For each start time of the driver, the working time within consecutive `working_time + break_time` is `working_time`

```
for driver_id in range(num_drivers):
     for start_shift_id in range(latest_start_shift + 1):
         model.Add(sum(driver_shifts[(driver_id, shift_id)] for shift_id in
                   range(start_shift_id, start_shift_id + working_time + break_time)) == working_time) \
             .OnlyEnforceIf(start_time[(driver_id, start_shift_id)])
```

### Break is contiguous

For this, we need an additional array `break_ind[(d, s, b)]` that denotes whether a given driver `d` with a given working shift start `s` takes a break at shift `b`. So, in this case, `driver_shifts` values should be `0` for the time of the break:

```
     l = start_shift_id + break_interval[0]
     r = start_shift_id + break_interval[1]
     for s in range(l, r):
        break_ind[(driver_id, start_shift_id, s)] = model.NewBoolVar("d%is%is%i"%(driver_id, start_shift_id, s))
        model.Add(sum(driver_shifts[(driver_id, s1)] for s1 in range(s, s + break_time)) == 0)\
        .OnlyEnforceIf(start_time[(driver_id, start_shift_id)])\
        .OnlyEnforceIf(break_ind[(driver_id, start_shift_id, s)])
```

Also, a driver can take a break only once a day:

```
model.Add(sum(break_ind[(driver_id, start_shift_id, s)] for s in range(l, r)) == 1)
```

## Full Code

You can check the full code below or [here](https://github.com/Tester2012/or-tools-scripts) (I added it for reference in the future). There you can also find a simplified version for a case when drivers don't take a break.

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
from math import ceil

shifts = [
    [0, '07:00', '07:30', 420, 450, 30],
    [1, '07:30', '08:00', 450, 480, 30],
    [2, '08:00', '08:30', 480, 510, 30],
    [3, '08:30', '09:00', 510, 540, 30],
    [4, '09:00', '09:30', 540, 570, 30],
    [5, '09:30', '10:00', 570, 600, 30],
    [6, '10:00', '10:30', 600, 630, 30],
    [7, '10:30', '11:00', 630, 660, 30],
    [8, '11:00', '11:30', 660, 690, 30],
    [9, '11:30', '12:00', 690, 720, 30],
    [10, '12:00', '12:30', 720, 750, 30],
    [11, '12:30', '13:00', 750, 780, 30],
    [12, '13:00', '13:30', 780, 810, 30],
    [13, '13:30', '14:00', 810, 840, 30],
    [14, '14:00', '14:30', 840, 870, 30],
    [15, '14:30', '15:00', 870, 900, 30],
    [16, '15:00', '15:30', 900, 930, 30],
    [17, '15:30', '16:00', 930, 960, 30],
    [18, '16:00', '16:30', 960, 990, 30],
    [19, '16:30', '17:00', 990, 1020, 30],
    [20, '17:00', '17:30', 1020, 1050, 30],
    [21, '17:30', '18:00', 1050, 1080, 30],
    [22, '18:00', '18:30', 1080, 1110, 30],
    [23, '18:30', '19:00', 1110, 1140, 30],
    [24, '19:00', '19:30', 1140, 1170, 30],
    [25, '19:30', '20:00', 1170, 1200, 30],
    [26, '20:00', '20:30', 1200, 1230, 30],
    [27, '20:30', '21:00', 1230, 1260, 30],
    [28, '21:00', '21:30', 1260, 1290, 30],
    [29, '21:30', '22:00', 1290, 1320, 30],
    [30, '22:00', '22:30', 1320, 1350, 30],
    [31, '22:30', '23:00', 1350, 1380, 30],
    [32, '23:00', '23:30', 1380, 1410, 30],
    [33, '23:30', '24:00', 1410, 1440, 30]
]

class VarArraySolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    def __init__(self, driver_shifts, num_drivers, num_shifts, solutions):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.driver_shifts = driver_shifts
        self.num_drivers = num_drivers
        self.num_shifts = num_shifts
        self.solutions = solutions
        self.solution_id = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        if self.solution_id in self.solutions:
            self.solution_id += 1
            print ("Solution found!")
            for driver_id in range(self.num_drivers):
                print ("*************Driver#%s*************" % driver_id)
                for shift_id in range(self.num_shifts):
                    if (self.Value(self.driver_shifts[(driver_id, shift_id)])):
                        print('Shift from %s to %s' %
                              (shifts[shift_id][1],
                               shifts[shift_id][2]))
            print()

    def solution_count(self):
        return self.solution_id

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
model = cp_model.CpModel()

num_shifts = len(shifts)

working_time = 22
break_time = 2

# when take a break within the working time
break_interval = [8, 16]

latest_start_shift = num_shifts - working_time - break_time
num_drivers = ceil(float(num_shifts) / working_time)

# create an array of assignments of drivers
driver_shifts = {}
for driver_id in range(num_drivers):
    for shift_id in range(num_shifts):
        driver_shifts[(driver_id, shift_id)] = model.NewBoolVar('driver%ishift%i' % (driver_id, shift_id))

# driver must work exactly {working_time} shifts
for driver_id in range(num_drivers):
    model.Add(sum(driver_shifts[(driver_id, shift_id)] for shift_id in range(num_shifts)) == working_time)

# each shift must be covered by at least one driver
for shift_id in range(num_shifts):
    model.Add(sum(driver_shifts[(driver_id, shift_id)] for driver_id in range(num_drivers)) >= 1)

# create an array of start times for drivers
start_time = {}
for driver_id in range(num_drivers):
    for shift_id in range(latest_start_shift + 1):
        start_time[(driver_id, shift_id)] = model.NewBoolVar('driver%istart%i' % (driver_id, shift_id))

break_ind = {}
for driver_id in range(num_drivers):
     for start_shift_id in range(latest_start_shift + 1):
         model.Add(sum(driver_shifts[(driver_id, shift_id)] for shift_id in
                   range(start_shift_id, start_shift_id + working_time + break_time)) == working_time) \
             .OnlyEnforceIf(start_time[(driver_id, start_shift_id)])

         l = start_shift_id + break_interval[0]
         r = start_shift_id + break_interval[1]
         for s in range(l, r):
            break_ind[(driver_id, start_shift_id, s)] = model.NewBoolVar("d%is%is%i"%(driver_id, start_shift_id, s))
            model.Add(sum(driver_shifts[(driver_id, s1)] for s1 in range(s, s + break_time)) == 0)\
            .OnlyEnforceIf(start_time[(driver_id, start_shift_id)])\
            .OnlyEnforceIf(break_ind[(driver_id, start_shift_id, s)])
         model.Add(sum(break_ind[(driver_id, start_shift_id, s)] for s in range(l, r)) == 1)

for driver_id in range(num_drivers):
    model.Add(sum(start_time[(driver_id, start_shift_id)] for start_shift_id in range(latest_start_shift + 1)) == 1)

solution_printer = VarArraySolutionPrinter(driver_shifts, num_drivers, num_shifts, range(2))
status = solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_printer)
```

Comment: Hi @Anatolii Many thanks for the detailed answer! Amazing explanation as well.

Comment: I was wondering if it possible to connect a specific weight to each hour so as to gravitate the shifts towards high-weight hours?