# Optimize breaks in scheduling problem using ortools

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66831152/modified-bus-scheduling-problem-in-ortools) question that successfully allocates N drivers to working slots and creates breaks, I was wondering if it is possible to **i)** force the solver to minimise possible overlap in drivers' breaks? and **ii)** maintain the highest number of drivers active during the break.

Comment: @Anatolii *ping*

Comment: Hey, sorry, I'm busy these days - maybe I'll more time next week. One brute force approach is to enforce that the number of "driving" drivers is always `1`, and keep increasing the number of drivers if there's no solution.

Comment: @Anatolii Yes, but this does not take into account that the breaks of the remaining drivers do not overlap

Comment: @Anatolii Hi Anatoli, any news ?